# How to reference observational evidence?

Tags: publications, citations, writing

Talking about work practices at a business, and hearing first hand from the manager how the employees conduct their work - how can I reference this anecdotal evidence in an academic paper? Alternatively, I could discount the anecdotal evidence and instead conduct an analysis of the work environment myself (i.e. looking at how the work environment operates) - but then I am left in the position of referencing myself! Please advise.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: You can put the name of the person in the bibliography and say "Personal communication."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea is that you can perform some *formal* or *informal* **interviews** with parties involved in the subject of your research / interest. This is pretty much a standard research method for *qualitative* studies. Then, you can reference those interviews in a traditional way (in accordance with your preferred publication style guide), in addition to placing them in one of appendices of your paper as well as summarizing and analyzing the facts toward discovering some patterns or other findings.

Comment: Don't forget to get Institutional Review Board approval of your interviewing plans and (as part of that plan) informed consent from your subjects. Your interview questions are unlikely to be seen as able to cause the subjects harm, so the IRB approval should be easy. No reputable journal will accept your article which is now a human subjects research project without a statement that it was approved by and IRB.

Comment: @BillBarth: You're right - excellent point (+1). I forgot about that aspect, since my dissertation didn't require an IRB approval.